# How task manager assign priority to processes?

Tags: operating-system

can anyone have an idea about my question.
I need to know about how **task manager assign priorities** in windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the scheduler, in an OS you have a lot of things running "at the same time", actually there is a scheduler giving access to the CPU to a certain process, while a process is waiting for the CPU it gains "points", then the scheduler gives the CPU to the highest amount of points (that is what I was teached).

The priority will make the process gain more or less points while it is waiting.